# Javascript with Apache 2 Proxy rewrite rules and Plone

Tags: javascript, proxy, apache2, url-rewriting, plone

I have a Plone site behind and Apache2 Proxy server that has two web pages that uses a java script.  That Plone site and Java Script functions correct with out that Apache 2 Proxy Server.  Plone does function correctly with it's web Plone pages behind the proxy server.  However the JavaScript is not working correctly with the Apache proxy servers.  Please see below Apache access logs.  I believe the reason has to with the Javascript try to post to the wrong location.  If you look at the GET services and I believe the POST is coming back from the java script and it's posting to services/services.  So would anybody have and idea for correct Apache rewrite to correct this problem?  Posted below are the rules I have been trying.

```
My host - - [24/Mar/2013:21:16:16 -0400] **"GET /services** HTTP/1.0" 200 19149 "http://rcms.xxxx.com/our-team" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.172 Safari/537.22"
184.56.129.45 - - [24/Mar/2013:21:16:17 -0400] "GET /portal_css/HedDex%20Tranquility%20Plone3%20Theme/resourceplone.app.jquerytools.overlays-cachekey8212.css HTTP/1.0" 200 2023 "http://rcms.xxxx.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.172 Safari/537.22"
My Host - - [24/Mar/2013:21:16:18 -0400] "POST **/services/services/@@merged**Request/getMergedData HTTP/1.0" 200 16826 "http://rcms.xxxx.com/services" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.172 Safari/537.22"
```

Rules:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$
balancer://lbesa/siteX/rbt/VirtualHostBase/http/rcms.xxxx.com:80/siteX/rdt/VirtualHostRoot/$1 [L,P]

ProxyPassReverse /services/
balancer://lbesa/VirtualHostBase/http/rcms.xxxx.com:80/siteX/rdt/VirtualHostRoot/services/services/
```

Comment: The mixing of RewriteRule with ProxyPassReverse may be a recipe for mental illness. It's possible to do it, but it complicates the picture. Is there a reason why you aren't doing this with rewriterules alone?

Comment: How do you determine where to post *to* from javascript? It doesn't matter what your rewrite rules are, it's what JS thinks is the correct URL that is at stake here.

Comment: Surely /services/services, to a Plone site, is going to find /services anyway, by acquisition. So, I'd suggest Steve's right. The RewriteLog would be helpful.  Also, I'm not thrilled about using balancer: before  testing your rewrite rules. I do use balancer:, but try one at a time.

Comment: Hi Steve M and Auspex,  The answer to your question regarding RewriteRule and ProxyPassReverse is I was trying something.  I would be happy to uses one or the other.  I can also remove the balancer.  It have had removed before and made no difference.  There are no errors or exception coming up in Plone.  This has been the only clue I have been able to find to the root problem.  Seem like to completely a javascript/Apache proxy thing!  Any ideas for a cleaner set of rules?

Comment: question I came across this:

Comment: http://www.eng.ox.ac.uk/Plone/solaris/apache-setup

Comment: under Using the apache module mod_ext_filter to re-write links in the page body I won't be able to or get more info until Thursday.  But what do you think?

Comment: I also found this:http://developer.plone.org/hosting/apache.html#reverse-proxy-host

<location /media>
        RedirectMatch /media/(.*)$ http://www2.site.fi/media/$1
</location>

Comment: Using the Virtual Host Monster to re-write links in the page body? Anybody up on this?

Comment: I have the answer the problem had do to a hard drive that was failing on the Apache proxy server.  Everything now works!