# Have an issue completely removing from "Products.qPloneDropDownMenu.browser" from Plone

Tags: plone

I am getting the following error when trying to uses a another product in Plone.  I uninstall the below production and rebuilt Plone without it.  But appears that there is something left over from when it was installed.  Any ideas on how to remove this package completely?

This is no longer installed

```
"Products.qPloneDropDownMenu.browser"

Request URL   
http://x.x.x.x:8080/site2/xxx/portal_cache_settings/cache_tool_config

Traceback (innermost last):
    Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 125, in publish
    Module Zope2.App.startup, line 238, in commit
    Module transaction._manager, line 96, in commit
    Module transaction._transaction, line 395, in commit
    Module transaction._transaction, line 495, in _commitResources
    Module ZODB.Connection, line 510, in commit
    Module ZODB.Connection, line 555, in _commit
    Module ZODB.Connection, line 582, in _store_objects
    Module ZODB.serialize, line 407, in serialize
    Module ZODB.serialize, line 416, in _dump
PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'Products.qPloneDropDownMenu.browser.interfaces.IQPloneDropDownMenuLayer'>: import of module Products.qPloneDropDownMenu.browser.interfaces failed
```

Comment: Thank you for report as soon as we have workaround or fix we'll post an answer here.

Comment: @wwiblinjr: Were you able to resolve anything?

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcard.fixpersitentutilities to remove the persistent class, read this post from David Breitkreutz for detailed informations:

http://davidjb.com/blog/2010/06/plone-sitemanager-leftovers-not-the-good-kind/

Answer (score 0):

If the (still right) answer of using fixpersitentutilities is not working for you, sometimes we use this clean but longer way:

1) re-add the product that create the problem
2) reinstall it
3) manually provide the missing uninstall Generic Setup uninstall step.

In your case, you need to add the "uninstall" profile, with (at least) a browserlayer.xml
So this is it:

```
<layers>
   <layer name="qPloneDropDownMenu"
     interface="Products.qPloneDropDownMenu.browser.interfaces.IQPloneDropDownMenuLayer"
     remove="True" />
</layers>
```

4) uninstall again

Comment: Fixed had to do with old apps installed under parts versus adding third part app thru buildout.  I just add the missing app in parts directory which get removed each time a new buildout is preformed.

Comment: @wwiblinjr: Can you update and accept or just close your quest then, please? TIA.

Comment: @wwiblinjr: Same goes for your other quest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617854/javascript-with-apache-2-proxy-rewrite-rules-and-plone, thanks!